# JavaScript keyboard events and detection

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to stay clear of jQuery and want to detect if the left or right key is pressed. I am having trouble just getting this to work.

```
var keyPress = function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  if (keyCode == 37)
    //do something
  if (keyCode == 39)
    //do something
}
document.onkeydown = keyPress(event);
```

The problem I am having is that I just cannot detect any keyboard events.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have u checked if firebug is throwing any error ?

Comment: If you don't have jQuery or another library to normalise it for you you might want to say something like `var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;` (and possibly `if (!event) event = window.event`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the function reference to onkeydown

```
document.onkeydown = keyPress;
```

what you are doing to calling the function `keyPress` and passing the value returned by it as the `onkeydown` handler, in this case `undefined`.